# Confused about language environment and encoding

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

Below is my locale set.

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

If i change LC_CTYPE to en_US.UTF-8 then i can't input Chinese character in terminal or other applications. Why? What's the function of the prefix: en_US or zh_CN in LC_TYPE?

If i want to input Chinese word then i set LC_CTYPE=zh_CN, if i want to input another language (Assume it is X) word then i set LC_CTYPE=X. But if i want to input both Chinese and X, so what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LC_CTYPE` applies to classification and conversion of characters, and to multibyte and wide characters.

`zh` is the ISO-Code for Chinese. `zh_CN` is a subtype of `zh` and stands for "simplified Chinese".

Comment: I still don't know why i can't input Chinese character, if i change LC_CTYPE to en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Because in en_US you only have onebyte characters. For chinese glyphes you need multibyte characters

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can export language environment for each bash session, so if you set LANG etc and start X session in the same script - this language will be accepted to the whole X Session. 
For instance, following script starts VNC session for german language and it is independant from system language. You can add needed environment variables for needed input layouts here and get needed result for each X session.

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=de_DE:de
vnc4server -depth 16 -geometry 1024x768 :1
vncconfig -iconic -nowin -display :1 &
```